# Capistrano: conditionally run commands after deploy on remote

Tags: capistrano, deployment

I want to remove some folders on the remote once deploy has completed.   I am currently using

```
task :set_permissions do

  parallel do |session|
    session.when "in?(:xb_test)", "cat #{deploy_to}test.htaccess >> #{current_path}/.htaccess"
  end
```

Two questions really, is this the best way to do this and how can I run this kind of statement on multiple functions without having to write repeat code?

```
session.when "in?(:xb_test)" ...
session.when "in?(:xb_dev)" ...
session.when "in?(:xb_live)" ...
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm pretty new to Capistrano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- About your first question, "is this the best way to do this ?" :

  I don't think this is the best approach.
  "test" "dev" and "live" uhm... it looks like you are deploying to different stages, then I would better use https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension
- About your second question, "how can I run this kind of statement on multiple functions without having to write repeat code ?":

  capistrano deploy.rb is just a ruby file, you can use a method

```
    def htaccess_stuff
      "cat #{deploy_to}test.htaccess >> #{current_path}/.htaccess"
    end
```

and then

```
task :set_permissions do

  parallel do |session|
    session.when "in?(:xb_test)", htaccess_stuff
  end
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I'll take a look at the multistage extension.